# LTS pre-release or 2-year old LTS than upgrade? Which has less headaches historically?

Tags: 14.04, server, upgrade, 16.04

Opinion requested for your Ubuntu LTS experts!

So in the next couple of weeks I really, really need a new AWS instance that runs Ubuntu LTS. The current one of course in 14.04, but I'd rather have 16.04. But, the official release is still months away! Since this computer will be for a development environment, but probably cool with having a pre-release version, it really just comes down to what's less of a pain to upgrade. What takes less time headaches, etc. This server will have Jenkins, nGinx, PHP, node, git, standard dev stuff.

So, would you:

1. Make a 14.04 LTS server now, and upgrade to 16.04 LTS in early May? , or
2. Make a 16.04 LTS pre-release server now, and upgrade to full release in early May?

It's a question of time and/or stability/package headaches.

Thank you!

Comment: I'm no expert, but I'd imagine that starting with 14.04 and upgrading to 16.04 would be easier than starting with 16.04 pre-release, mainly because the pre-release may be buggy.

Comment: Historically, mature releases are much more stable than early ones. Note that Ubuntu is focusing heavily on mobile and so Desktop and Server releases are not going to have that many new features, but anyway I'd always go for the mature release for a server environment and even upgrade prod servers only 2-3 Months after the new release, just to be sure I don't eat every possible bug, unless you need a specific new feature packed in the new release.

Comment: Thank you! I don't know I why I can't select this answer, but I will stick to 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

When you talk pre-released this is almost always going to be more of a headache as it is being used to test (so less bugs will be in the actual release) You are better off installing 14.04Lts that is supported tell April 2019. Then updating to the new release when it is supported  (In April 2016)

*Note as @EduardoLopez pointed out even when 16 is released it may still have bugs that were not found by the Alfa or other pre-release's